# For which $n$ is the variety of groups of exponent $\mid n$ locally finite?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, universal-algebra

What is known about this question ?

The $n=2$ case is an elementary exercise, and if I'm not wrong it works for prime $n$ as well (if you have a refernce/proof of that, that would be great).
But what about composite $n$ ? Is it still open in general ?  What are some interesting references ?

Comment: This is the Burnside problem. Groups of exponent $n$ are not locally finite for sufficiently large $n$ (about $n > 800$ I think). They are locally finite for $n=2,3,4,6$, and it is unknown for intermediate values, including $n=5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : aren't they locally finite for all prime $n$ ?

Comment: See [Burnside problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem) for more details.

Comment: @Max What's the proof that you think works for all prime $n$? The proof I have in mind for exponent $2$ goes by showing that all groups of exponent $2$ are abelian, which is not true for other prime exponents.

Comment: @AlexKruckman : No I have no proof for prime $n$ (which is reassuring considrring what Derek Holt said), and clearly the proof for $2$ does not go through for other primes, but I had read somewhere that someone solved this and it was locally finite for primes; but I must have misread